# Adjusting line-height of label elements in HTML forms

Tags: html, label, forms, css

I have a form with a wrapping `<label>` element, but the space between the `<label>`'s two lines is too big and I can't seem to adjust the line-height of the `<label>`.

Here is an example of a `<label>` and a `<p>`, both with the same CSS applied.  As you can see, the `<p>` adjusts correctly, while the `<label>` remains unchanged.

http://jsfiddle.net/QYzPa/

**CODE:**

```css
form label,
form p
{    
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:.7em;
}
```

```html
<form style="width:200px;">
    <fieldset>
         <label for="textarea">In ten or fewer words, explain American history</label>
        <p>In ten or fewer words, explain American history</p>
        <textarea name="textarea" rows="5" ></textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All the HTML tags are classified in categories that describe their nature. This classification can be related to semantics, behavior, interaction and many other aspects.

Both `p` and `label` tags are classified in "flow content" tags category. But there is one slight difference between then: the `label` tag is also classified in a category called "phrasing content".

What do all this mean in practice? The browser default rendering will follow the specified tag classifications and will treat the `p` tag as a block element, while the `label` tag will, by default, be treated as an in-line element. You can modify this by overwriting the default CSS rule: just tell the browser that you want your `label` to be rendered like a block element.

```
label {
  display: block;
}
```

You need to do that because elements that are in-line (display:inline) can't have properties like `height`, `line-height`, `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` (they will be ignored).

If you want an inline element to have a height property but still keep it with it's inline behavior (without cause a LINE BREAK), you can declare it as:

```
label{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

It's always good to take a read at HTML 's documentation. [Here is a nice graph showing the categories](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#kinds-of-content), it can save you a lot of time, specially when dealing with these small quirks.

Comment: Way to lay it out- display:block; was indeed the issue- thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think what's Marcio is trying to say is that in `inline` elements (like `span`s or `label`s), which can reside one after another in the text, you can't specify attributes that apply to the whole paragraph.

The obvious one is `text-align`: the paragraph should specify the align and not the individual `span`s. So as `line-height` and such.

The opposite to the `inline` elements are the `block` elements like `div` or `p` which occupy a square on a page and are laid out between each other on a higher block-level. This behavior is controlled with the CSS attribute [`display`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)  with which can make `div` behave just like `span` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why, but it will work if you set `display: block;` on the label