# Is HTML label a replaced element?

Tags: html, css

First, a definition of replaced element [from W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element) :

> ### Replaced element
>
> An element whose content is outside the scope of the
>   CSS formatting model, such as an image, embedded document, or applet.
>   For example, the content of the HTML IMG element is often replaced by
>   the image that its "src" attribute designates. Replaced elements often
>   have intrinsic dimensions: an intrinsic width, an intrinsic height,
>   and an intrinsic ratio. For example, a bitmap image has an intrinsic
>   width and an intrinsic height specified in absolute units (from which
>   the intrinsic ratio can obviously be determined). On the other hand,
>   other documents may not have any intrinsic dimensions (for example, a
>   blank HTML document).
>
> User agents may consider a replaced element to not have any intrinsic
>   dimensions if it is believed that those dimensions could leak
>   sensitive information to a third party. For example, if an HTML
>   document changed intrinsic size depending on the user's bank balance,
>   then the UA might want to act as if that resource had no intrinsic
>   dimensions.
>
> The content of replaced elements is not considered in the CSS
>   rendering model.

It doesn't seem to concern `label`, right?

Then, I've seen [this blog post](http://demosthenes.info/blog/461/What-The-Heck-Is-A-Replaced-Element), which gives this one rule :

> You cannot apply generated content to replaced elements. That is, you
>   cannot apply the pseudo-element selectors :before or :after to them.

But I can.

**So, I can assume it's not a replaced element (I lack of experiences to prove the opposite).**

---

So, according to [MDN's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) about `line-height` :

> Case 1 - On **block level elements**, the line-height CSS property specifies the
>   minimal height of line boxes within the element.
>
> Case 2 - On **non-replaced inline elements**, line-height specifies the height that
>   is used in the calculation of the line box height.
>
> Case 3 - On **replaced inline elements**, like buttons or other input element,
>   line-height has no effect.

I set up JSfiddles to illustrate these behaviors, comparing a block element (`div`) and label :

- [Setting specific `line-height` directly on `div` and `label`](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/uGr27/2/) - OK
- [Setting `line-height` on wrapping form, and override it on `div` and `label`](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/uGr27/3/) - Not OK, the two elements behave differently
- [Setting `line-height` on wrapping form, `label` displayed as a block, overriding `line-height` on `label` and `block`](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/uGr27/1/) - OK

So, `label` behave like a non-replaced element, but when it comes to override `line-height`, it does not.

#### I don't get it, does someone have any explanation of this behavior? Is label a replaced element after all?

*On [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html), I've seen that `label` is in the Phrasing content category, an I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6246422/1437016), but I did not find an answer to my question with it.*

<sup>Tests were made under Chrome 33 (Mac).</sup>

Comment: The point in the question seems to be that `line-height` set on a `label` element behaves contrary to some expectations in a certain context. This phenomenon, well addressed in @Quentin’s answer, is in no way unique to `label` elements. You get the same behavior e.g. for `span` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is HTML label a replaced element?

No

> > You cannot apply generated content to replaced elements. That is, you cannot apply the pseudo-element selectors :before or :after to them.
>
> But I can.

The quote says you can't use `:before` or `:after` on *replaced elements*.

Since `label` is *not* a replaced element, you *can* use `:before` and `:after` on it.

So you aren't seeing anything that contradicts the documentation  you are reading.

---

> Setting line-height on wrapping form, and override it on div and label - Not OK, the two elements behave differently

They *should* behave differently.

The inline boxes inside the form are the line height for the form.

The label is inline, so its inline boxes go inside the inline boxes for the form. The label's inline boxes are smaller than the inline boxes they are inside.

The div is a block element, so its inline boxes go inside the div itself and not inside the inline boxes for the form.

If you [make the div `display: inline`](http://jsfiddle.net/uGr27/4/) then you compare two elements that are `display: inline` instead of one that is `inline` and one that is `block` and you get the same results for each.

Comment: Alright, I think I went to far on `replaced` elements, I was to focused on it to see that the problem wasn't here. Thank you for your clarifications!